Error in Rmarkdown with latex and gglikert() related
I have two R files.One R script called "execute" that executes a render function. Calls an R markdown file called "Generator.Rmd". This R markdown does some calculations. Actually will create so many pdfs as the unique years in the df data frame.
R script
path = "/Users/.../"

library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
likert_levels <- c(
  "1" = "Very  Dissatisfied",
  "2" = "Dissatisfied",
  "3" = "Neutral",
  "4" = "Satisfied",
  "5" = "Very  Satisfied")
df = data.frame(
  year = sample(c(2023, 2022, 2020, 2018), 50, replace = TRUE),
  A = sample(likert_levels, 50, replace = TRUE),
  B = sample(likert_levels, 50, replace = TRUE),
  C = sample(likert_levels, 50, replace = TRUE))%>%
  mutate(across(everything(),as.factor))%>%
  as_tibble()%>%
  mutate(across(-year, ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels)))



for (i in unique(df$year)){
  df_year = df%>%
    dplyr::filter(year == i)
  
  rmarkdown::render(
    # 1. Search for your base report
    input =  paste0(path,"Generator.Rmd"),
    # 2. Establish the format
    output_format = "pdf_document",        
    # 3. Define the output file name
    output_file = paste0(i, "_report.pdf"),
    # 4. Define an output folder/directory
    output_dir  = path, 
    # 5. Integrate your parameters
    params = list(year = i, 
                  DFEmpRecords   =  df_year))}


R Markdown script
---
geometry: top=1cm , bottom= 2cm , left=0.5cm, right=0.5cm
header-includes:
- \PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,table}{xcolor}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{rotating}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \usepackage{readarray}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{epstopdf}
classoption: table
output:
  pdf_document: default
params: 
  year: 0
  DFEmpRecords: 0 
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstats)
```


```{r , echo=FALSE , warning=FALSE , message = FALSE ,fig.width=10, fig.height=9 , dpi= 600}
YEAR = params$year
DF   = params$DFEmpRecords
```





```{r, echo=FALSE , warning=FALSE , message = FALSE ,fig.width=8, fig.height=9, dpi= 1200}


 category = DF%>%
   as_tibble()%>%
   dplyr::select(A,B,C)%>%
   dplyr::mutate(across(everything(),  ~ case_when(
    . == "1" ~ likert_levels["1"],
    . == "2" ~ likert_levels["2"],
    . == "3" ~ likert_levels["3"],
    . == "4" ~ likert_levels["4"],
    . == "5" ~ likert_levels["5"])))%>%
  dplyr::mutate(across(everything(), ~ factor(.x, levels
                                              =likert_levels)))%>%
  as.data.frame()%>%
  ggstats::gglikert()
category

```

I am receiving an error that relates to latex . Can someone tell what is wrong here ?

Error: LaTeX failed to compile /Users/.../_report.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.


Works fine for me, except that I got an empty plot but that's a different issue. My guess is that you need to update your Latex installation. Searching for "Error: LaTeX failed to compile" on the Web gave me for example https://forum.posit.co/t/r-markdown-doesnt-create-pdf-file-latex-failed-to-compile/92247

@stefan I have updated tinytex but the error remains

I initially had the same error as you've shown here, but there is a LOT more context to that error. What else did your error say?  For me I was missing one Latex file and TeX Live wasn't current. The instructions in the error message stated to update Tex Live with  tinytex::reinstall_tinytex(). After following the instructions in the most useful error message I've ever seen, your files ran with no issue.
